# Strong Named Assembly And Public Key Token

Tags: .net, clr, metadata, .net-assembly, strongname

Consider a situation when two public keys of two different publishers’ assemblies are mapped to the same public key **token** (while name, version and culture of the assemblies are also the same).

When the CLR will try to resolve an AssemblyRef entry that intended to reference only one of the above, will it be able to know exactly which one should be loaded?
I’m sure nothing is left for luck, so how will it work?
Maybe it's a tradeoff, having shorter keys, saving space with the risk of collisions?

source: CLR via C#, 4th edition, page 71 (head).

Comment: I have the same question (while reading the same book). I can only assume that the additional risk of collision introduced by using a token rather than the entire public key, is considered minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ambiguity when the assembly is stored in the GAC, one assembly will *replace* the other.  So you'll get whichever was registered last.

When it is not stored in the GAC then the CLR will only ever locate an assembly based on the display name.  It searches through the directories in the probing path for a file whose filename matches the display name with a file extension of .exe or .dll.  First one it finds completes the search, kaboom if the rest of the AssemblyName doesn't match.  You'll have a hard time storing an assembly with the same display name in the same directory, but it is technically possible to have one named .exe and the other named .dll.  The .exe is found first.

This is all rather well documented in this [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: **1.** so there is a little "hell" here, one assembly overrides the other although they have different public keys. it's pretty reasonable as the GAC folders structures based on the public key token.
**2.** strong named assemblies loaded outside the GAC, AFAIK the CLR will use the version and key info, and also will validate the signature when the assembly is loaded for the first time. **3.** dll and exe files with same name, dll loaded first

Comment: Pretty hard to guess how you arrived at these conclusions.  1: no, you stated that the public keys were the same.  2: no, the CLR will only verify it after it loaded the assembly, kaboom on a mismatch with no additional search. 3: no, exe is first.  Thanks for the helpful vote.

Comment: I'm here to learn, so first I'd like to thank you for your attention and your time :)
**1.** "two public keys of two different publishers" - I stated that the mapped token is the same, not the original full public key. the "hell" is if the name, culture, version and token will be the same even if the full key is different.  
**2.** ok, I understand now 
**3.** I tried that, it took my dll first. they were unsigned but with the same name.